# How do I uninstall `libllvm3.8 (1:3.8-2ubuntu4)` and install `libllvm3.8 (= 1:3.8-2ubuntu1)`?

Tags: clang, ubuntu-16.04, llvm-clang, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to install UnrealEngine4 by following the instructions here: https://github.com/Microsoft/AirSim/blob/master/docs/build_linux.md.

When I run `./Setup.sh` in the UnrealEngine4 repository, I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clang-3.8 : Depends: libclang1-3.8 (= 1:3.8-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libobjc-5-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libclang-common-3.8-dev (= 1:3.8-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: llvm-3.8-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This led me to try installing `llvm-3.8-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install llvm-3.8-dev
```

Which finally led to this problem:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 llvm-3.8-dev : Depends: libllvm3.8 (= 1:3.8-2ubuntu1) but 1:3.8-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I uninstall `libllvm3.8 (1:3.8-2ubuntu4)`?

Additional info:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep llvm
ri  libllvm3.8:amd64                                            1:3.8-2ubuntu4                                amd64        Modular compiler and toolchain technologies, runtime library

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove llvm-3.8-dev`?

Comment: Okay, I ran `sudo apt-get autoremove llvm-3.8-dev`. Then I ran `sudo apt-get install llvm-3.8-dev` and got the same error: `llvm-3.8-dev : Depends: libllvm3.8 (= 1:3.8-2ubuntu1) but 1:3.8-2ubuntu4 is to be installed`

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove libllvm3.8` results in `gnuplot5-x11 : Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
 libwayland-egl1-mesa : Depends: libegl1-mesa (= 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.`

Comment: Having the exact same problem trying to install clang3.8, with the "libllvm3.8" dependency error. I found no solution so far and installed clang3.7 instead. Any updates would be more than welcome though, thanks!

Comment: @Aldream: Are you trying to run `Setup.sh` for AirSim? If so, did installing clang3.7 work for you on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @CarsonTang No, it was for a different project I just joined. clang3.7 worked to compile it though...

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt install package=version

you should install the package adding a version number

sudo apt install llvm-3.8-dev=1:3.8-2ubuntu1